# Does unicode_type/string type work for Numba's cfunc?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, unicode, numba

I saw in Numba's [documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#str) that some operations with str type are supported. I tested it with @jit decorator and it certainly works:

```
In [14]: @numba.jit("boolean(unicode_type, unicode_type)")
...: def compare_str(a, b):
...:     return a == b
...:                  
In [15]: compare_str("a","a")                                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[15]: True
```

I was wondering if this type is also available for cfuncs, because I would like to have a C++ callback that does some operation on strings, but I am not able to test it succesfully in Python, although it actually compiles:

```
In [13]: @numba.cfunc("boolean(unicode_type, unicode_type)")
    ...: def compare_str(a, b):
    ...:     return a == b
    ...:    
In [12]: compare_str.ctypes("a","a")
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-63a3266c663d> in <module>
----> 1 compare_str.ctypes("a", "a")

~/.virtualenvs/py3cpp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/utils.py in __get__(self, instance, type)
    351         if instance is None:
    352             return self
--> 353         res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
    354         return res
    355

~/.virtualenvs/py3cpp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/ccallback.py in ctypes(self)
    159         A ctypes function object representing the C callback.
    160         """
--> 161         ctypes_args = [to_ctypes(ty) for ty in self._sig.args]
    162         ctypes_restype = to_ctypes(self._sig.return_type)
    163         functype = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes_restype, *ctypes_args)

~/.virtualenvs/py3cpp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/ccallback.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    159         A ctypes function object representing the C callback.
    160         """
--> 161         ctypes_args = [to_ctypes(ty) for ty in self._sig.args]
    162         ctypes_restype = to_ctypes(self._sig.return_type)
    163         functype = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes_restype, *ctypes_args)

~/.virtualenvs/py3cpp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/typing/ctypes_utils.py in to_ctypes(ty)
     80     if ctypeobj is None:
     81         raise TypeError("Cannot convert Numba type '%s' to ctypes type"
---> 82                         % (ty,))
     83     return ctypeobj
     84

TypeError: Cannot convert Numba type 'unicode_type' to ctypes type
```

I am using numba 0.42.0 and Python 3.6.7. Any hints will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not yet supported. It was answered in [Numba's public discussion Google group](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/numba-users/Vf0ssJHZBmg)